# If I'm looking for a string in a HTML file, should I process it as a string, or use a package like BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have a thousand HTML pages similar to [this page](http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projectLibrary/getProjInfoNational.do?projId=0008aa9b6bb04b9180d4d9a597b020b4).

For each HTML page, I want to download PDF files linked within the HTML pages. The source code reveals that ***all*** these links occur in between these two blocks of texts: `<a style="color:#167bd5;font-size:13px;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="perviewPdf(this)" url="` and `" target="_blank">`. I just need to add in some additional text, and this additional text is the same for ***every*** link.

For example, if the HTML document contains `<a style="color:#167bd5;font-size:13px;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="perviewPdf(this)" url="./ppp/projManage/perview.do?fileName=安康高新区世纪大道物有所值分析5.pdf&ftpFileName=20160509120519529.pdf" target="_blank">`, I need to extract `/ppp/projManage/perview.do?fileName=安康高新区世纪大道物有所值分析5.pdf&ftpFileName=20160509120519529.pdf`, and add `http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/` to the front and `&content=efmisweb&xsg=:8083/` to the back.

The PDF file I need to download is here: `http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projManage/perview.do?fileName=fileName=安康高新区世纪大道物有所值分析5.pdf&ftpFileName=20160509120519529.pdf&content=efmisweb&xsg=:8083/`

I'm thinking of using Python to extract the text I need and then download the file. I can think of two possible methods after I download the HTML files:

1) parse the HTML file as a text string, search for the substring using `find()`

2) parse the HTML file using libraries such as BeautifulSoup or HTMLParser, which can also look for the substring.

Which method is likely to be faster?

Comment: I take it this is a one-time thing? You download these pdfs and then you never use this program again? If so, regex is probably easier to use than BeatifulSoup or HTMLParser, especially since you've already identified a pattern you can use to extract the urls. P.S. I swear to god, if anyone links the "don't parse HTML with regex" post, I'll give them an earful about what "parsing" means and how it's different from extracting text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a timing comparison between a few approaches:

```
In [22]: %timeit [a.get('url') for a in BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('a', onclick='perviewPdf(this)')]
10 loops, best of 3: 59.6 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit [a.get('url') for a in BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').find_all('a', onclick='perviewPdf(this)')]
10 loops, best of 3: 42.3 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit lxml.html.fromstring(html).xpath('//a/@url')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.99 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit [t.split('"', 1)[0] for t in html.split('perviewPdf(this)" url="')[1:]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 41.7 µs per loop
```

If you have already downloaded all of the HTML files, parsing 1,000 files will take:

- 60 seconds with BeautifulSoup and the built-in `html.parser`.
- 42 seconds with BeautifulSoup and the lxml parser.
- 3 seconds with just lxml.
- 0.0417 seconds with string manipulation.

Downloading a single page takes me 2.27 seconds, so with a reasonable rate limit of two concurrent downloads per second, it will take you around 19 minutes to download all of the pages.

While extracting the urls with string manipulation is indeed faster, the speeds are insignificant when compared to the 19 minutes it takes to download the HTML.

Personally, I would use lxml because it's the simplest and fast enough. Using BeautifulSoup will increase your script runtime by about 3%, but it might be easier for you to work with for more complex HTML than XPath.

Comment: @wwl: If you do end up using BeautifulSoup, install lxml anyways. BeautifulSoup defaults to Python's built-in `html.parser` if you don't have anything better installed, which makes BeautifulSoup take 60ms to parse each page.

Answer (score 1):

You should use BeautifulSoup for parsing HTML content

Here is very simple example for your usecase:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
str='''<a style="color:#167bd5;font-size:13px;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="perviewPdf(this)" url="./ppp/projManage/perview.do?fileName=安康高新区世纪大道物有所值分析5.pdf&ftpFileName=20160509120519529.pdf"/>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(str)
print soup.find_all('a')[0].get('url')
```

Output:

```
./ppp/projManage/perview.do?fileName=安康高新区世纪大道物有所值分析5.pdf&ftpFileName=20160509120519529.pdf
```

BeautifulSoup Tutorial : http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python